# Ncar command Language

Tags: 14.04

Hello I work with NCL (Ncar command language) to draw maps.
But, When I use it under Crontab, It does not work.
Have you ever encoutered this problem ?

When I write in a terminal:  ncl myscript.ncl  , it works

My crontab line does not work, which is :

```
9 17 * * * ncl /home/gep-server-hs/WRF-Rayonnement/Build_WRF/WRFOUT/20181018_TO_20181101/myscript.ncl
```

even:

```
9 17 * * * /home/gep-server-hs/ncl-6.5.0/bin/ncl /home/gep-server-hs/WRF-Rayonnement/Build_WRF/WRFOUT/20181018_TO_20181101/myscript.ncl
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1086140/edit) your question and share your `crontab` line which doesn't work?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, references to files and executables need to be fully qualified, i.e. start from the `/` root directory. If the executable is a script, the same holds for every reference in the script.

Answer (score 1):

The `cron` runtime environment is different than the interactive environment which is also different from the at/batch environment.

Run this in each of your environments, then compare the files:

```
 (echo "=== set ===";set;echo "===env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias) >a_different_log
```

I did this, and got:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ ll *.environment
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt  10672 Oct 22 13:59 at.environment
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt  10672 Oct 22 13:57 batch.environment
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt   1031 Oct 22 14:00 cron.environment
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt 126378 Oct 22 13:55 interactive.environment
walt@bat:~(0)$ wc -l *.environment
   238 at.environment
   238 batch.environment
    48 cron.environment
  3642 interactive.environment
```

Some setting in your environment, needed for NCAR to work, is not set in the `cron` environment. You will have to set it manually, or wrap your command in a `bash` script that sets up the environment.